# Novel about a man waking to a world without life after hibernating, then hibernating while re-evolving life?

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I have vague memories of a novel I read decades ago, and am trying to find out what it was. I tried various "AI" services to identify it, but all failed. This is what I remember:

- It was possibly written in the '70s or '80s, perhaps earlier.
- A man wakes from hibernation to a world with no life.
- He initially survives by eating stores of canned food.
- He has a robot to help him, which already existed or which he built himself.
- He gives the robot instructions to start restoring life, initially from very simple beginnings such as a few grass seeds.
- He repeatedly sleeps or hibernates for long periods as robots work to evolve the world to the complex ecological state it had in the past.
- At one early stage, the world is entirely covered with grass.
- Multiple robots are created to do the work and become more sophisticated over time.
- I think that eventually humans are re-evolved and the novel ends with him joining them.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Answer (score 20):

*Second Ending* by James White. The robots propagate the grass from seeds found in his trouser turn-ups (why he was put to sleep wearing ordinary clothes, I don't know).

The people at the end have greenish skin (I read somewhere that this was because the picture of his wife that the robots based them on had gone green from age, but I don't know if this was canon).

> "James White again puts his medical background to use – albeit obliquely – in this post apocalyptic tale of Ross, a man put into Deep Sleep until a cure for his leukaemia is found. He is awakened to find robots running the hospital and discovers that not only is he the last human alive, but that all other life on Earth was destroyed by nuclear war.
>
> Initially traumatised by his situation, he begins to restructure the robot workforce, discovers some grass seed in the turn-ups of his trousers and instructs the robots to put him back to sleep, work on bringing the grass back to life and develop it in whatever way they can. During his subsequent Deep Sleeps the robots upgrade themselves, and Ross notices an increased self-awareness in Nurse SB (his personal attendant) with each awakening."

Comment: Wow, well done, and thank you very much! What you described definitely sounded correct. So I found the novel, have now re-read it, and confirmed it was the one I had in mind. I'd forgotten much of it, but thankfully the little I remembered and wrote here was almost completely accurate. I see it was published in 1961, hence even earlier than I thought it might be. And that in turn probably means I read it earlier than I'd guessed, very likely in the early to mid '70s. So around 50 years ago (!) I'm amazed that you identified the novel only 2 hours after I asked the question, when I'd spent mult

Comment: If one of the answers here solved your issue, @PossibleMemories, please take a moment and [accept it](//scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.